# Copy Constructor Pointer Object

Tags: c++, object, pointers

I have the following class with the 2 pointers to block

```
#ifndef SCORING_H
#define SCORING_H

#include "Block.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Scoring
{
    public:
        Scoring(Block *, Block*, string, string, double);
        virtual ~Scoring();
        Scoring(const Block& b1, const Block &b2);
    private:
        Block * b1;
        Block * b2;
        string path1;
        string path2;
        double val;
};

#endif // SCORING_H
```

Class Block is the following:

```
class Block {
    public :
        ///constructo
        Block(double, double, double, double, int, vector<LineElement*>);

        ///Setter functions
        void setID(int);
        void setTop(double);
        void setLeft(double);
        void setRight(double);
        void setBottom(double);
        void setLine(vector<LineElement*>);

        int getID();
        double getTop();
        double getLeft();
        double getBottom();
        double getRight();
        vector<LineElement*> getLine();

    private:
        int id;
        vector<LineElement*> Listline;
        double top;
        double left;
        double bottom;
        double right;
};

#endif // ELEMENT_H_INCLUDED
```

I want to know, Should I construct a copy constructor for "Block * b1;Block * b2" and how can I treat these 2 points in the class scoring.h?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing that `Block::getLine` just returns the `ListLine`? Remember that this will cause the whole vector top be _copied_ which might not be what you want. You should probably return a _reference_ instead, e.g. `vector<LineElement*>& getLine();`. If you don't want the callers to modify the vector then make it `const` (as well as the `getLine` function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a constructor other than plain and simple `Block::Block(const Block&)` then it's not a copy-constructor. If you want to make a constructor in `Scoring` taking two `Block` pointers it's most definitely is not a copy-constructor.

If you want a copy-constructor in `Scoring` it should be like this:

```
class Scoring
{
    // ...

    Scoring(const Scoring& other);

    // ...
};
```

Then in that constructor you copy from `other`:

```
Scoring::Scoring(const Scoring& other)
    : b1(new Block(*other.b1)),
      b2(new Block(*other.b2)),
      path1(other.path1),
      path2(other.path2),
      val(other.val)
{
}
```

Of course, you should probably make a copy-constructor for the `Block` class too, as it contains a vector of pointers, and if you don't you will have two vectors with pointers pointing to the same objects, and that will be bad when you delete these objects in one vector but not the other.

Comment: Ok i see. I just have this question. Am I forced as a rule to create a copy constructor when i have pointers? and in my case was it important to use it?

Comment: @HaniGoc If you _create_ the pointers in the object, then yes having a copy constructor is a must unless you want to have [dangling pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). I suggest you read about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).